# Firebase 3.6.9 Error: PERMISSION_DENIED accessing database on Node SDK

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

I am referring to https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start

I have node.js code as mentioned below:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require('mySdkJSONFile');
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
                    projectId: "myProjectId",
                    clientEmail: "myClientEmail",
                    apiKey: "myApiKey",
                    privateKey: "myPrivateKey"
                }),
    databaseURL: "....",
    databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
        uid: "my-service-worker"
    }
});
var db = admin.database();
var usersDB = db.ref("/users");
usersDB.set({
  name: "myName",
  date: "yesterday"
});
```

And in the database the rules are set as

```
{
 "rules": {
 "public": {
     ".read": false,
     ".write": false
  },
 "users": {
    "$uid": {
      ".read": "auth.uid == 'my-service-worker'",
      ".write": "auth.uid == 'my-service-worker'"
            }
          }
      }
}
```

If for "/user" I set read and write permissions to true, everything works fine, no config issues.

Comment: Keep in mind that [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters). If you are querying `/users`, then you need a rule that allows read access **at that level**, not at the level beneath it.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably having an issue with `my-service-worker` account. Take a look at the `Authentication` tab in your [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and check what you have in column `User UID` for that user. Make sure you're using the same name. Other than that, everything should be fine.

In general, `uid` is a complex auto-generated string. I'm not sure how you would be able to create a custom string such as the one you're entering.

Comment: but what about the code snippet mentioned at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start

Comment: @manntsheth notice what the doc you refer says: "In this custom auth object, set the uid field to the identifier you used to represent your service in your Security Rules." So, are you using the uid to reference your actual service account, and not just 'my-service-worker'?

Answer (score 0):

Change in the users rules was needed, "$uid" was not needed. As mentioned in the same link I mentioned in the question (finding silly myself) https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start

```
{
 "rules": {
   "public": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": false
   },
   "users": {
     ".read": "auth.uid === 'my-service-worker'",
     ".write": "auth.uid === 'my-service-worker'"
   }
 }
}
```